# Use of assign event Action to another event Action

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, action

Given the following code:

```
public class A
{
    public event Action SomethingChangedA = null;

    public void Trigger()
    {
        SomethingChangedA?.Invoke();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public A a;
    public event Action SomethingChangedB = null;

    public B()
    {
        a = new A();
        //First approach
        a.SomethingChangedA += SomethingChangedB;
        //Second approach
        a.SomethingChangedA += () => SomethingChangedB?.Invoke();
    }
}

public class C
{
    public B b;

    public C()
    {
        b = new B();
        b.SomethingChangedB += DoSomethingOnC;
    }

    public void DoSomethingOnC()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something!");
    }
}
```

If I call:

```
C c = new C();
A a = c.b.a;

a.Trigger();
```

My first thought is that the output will be "`Something`" 2 times, but the fact is that the first approach is not called.

After a little bit of thinking about it, makes sense in my mind that:

```
a.SomethingChangedA += SomethingChangedB;
```

Is not calling something, but instead is just assign in the...reference of the memory reserved for the action?

I thought I knew what was happening and why this happens, but I'm not smart enough to explain it to another person... so probably I don't really know why is this happening.

So I've two questions:

1. How can I explain why this is happening?
2. What type of case will use this approach of assign in the action to
   another action?

Answer (score 0):

I think of SomethingChangedA as a collection of callbacks.

> a.SomethingChangedA += SomethingChangedB;

registers SmoethingChangedB in this collection. When triggered all subscribed methods get invoked.

Looking at the two approaches: approach two is lazy. So when actually invoked, SomethingChangedB is evaluated and SomethingChangedB is not assigned in the constructor.

Comment: I don't get it, SomethingChangedB is asigned in the constructor, the same place with method 1 and 2 :(

Comment: No, method 2 assigns a function that assignes the value when called.